# Netcat UDP transfer never stop until terminated via CTRL+C

Tags: linux, linux-networking, netcat

I'm trying to send data across machine using **Netcat** using **UDP** instead of **TCP**.

Now, unlike TCP(Netcat over TCP) which used to mark the completion of the file transfer by exiting the `nc` process, the UDP(Netcat over UDP) process never seem to exit, unless done forcefully using CTRL+C

> Example
>
> $ pv upd_mnl_client.rb | nc -u 192.168.1.117 5555
>
> 385 B 0:00:00 [39.8kiB/s] [==================================================================>] 100%
>       ^C ## I have to do this because the process never exit

Any Clue what I'm missing above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify `--send-only`, so it has no way to know whether or not you're done receiving. If you want it to receive data too, then you'll have to tell it when you're done. If you don't want it to receive data, specify `--send-only`.

Comment: Can you provide me link through this so that I can read through more about it. Since the man [page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) has nothing that explain that.

Comment: You can start [here](https://nmap.org/book/ncat-man-misc-options.html) or [here](http://www.pkill.info/linux/man/1-ncat/).

Comment: @DavidScwartz Thanks. Just one last question though the listening `nc client` has to be started with `--recv-only` correct? or `nc -ul [ip] [port] > upd_mnl_client.rb ` is good enough.

Comment: I don't think so. You're not expecting the listening program to stop by itself, are you? (How would it know?)

Comment: I guess I was like it used to work over TCP.

Comment: TCP has a way to say "I'm done". UDP doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You might could use the UDP timeout feature for this. For example:

```
nc -ul -i5 <port>
```

This will time a UDP listener out after 5 seconds.